# Visualizing Eigenvectors in 2D

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, visualization

The stochastic matrix
$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{cc}%
0.9 & 0.2\\
0.1 & 0.8
\end{array}
\right)
$$

has a dominant eigenvectors of
$u_{1}=\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{c}%
2\,\\
1\,
\end{array}
\right)  $. The second eigenvector is $u_{2}=\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{c}%
1\,\\
-1
\end{array}
\right)  $. The corresponding eigenvalues are $1$ and $0.7$, respectively.
I am trying to visualize what happens when we repeatedly multiply a vector by
$A$.
$$
Ax,~A^{2}x,~...
$$

Let $x$ be any vector that is not an eigenvector. In the matrix product $Ax$,
the matrix $A$ transforms $x$ and changes its direction. Loosely speaking, the
direction of $Ax$ is closer to the direction of $u_{1}$, the dominant eigenvector, than the original $x$.
We can repeat this transformation and in the limit, we have that the two
vectors coincide.
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}A^{k}x=u_{1}%
$$
In the figure below, the directions of the two eigenvectors are indicated by
black dashed lines. The orange line is perpendicular to the dominant
eigenvector. I have two questions.

1. Consider the two vectors a and b (both in blue, lower right). Repeated multiplication
   of $a$ by $A$ will take it towards $\left(  2,1\right)  ^{\prime}$. Since $b$
   is on the other side of the orange line, repeated multiplication of $b$ by $A$
   will take it towards $\left(  -2,-1\right)  ^{\prime}$. But what happens if a
   vector is EXACTLY on the orange line?
2. Consider vector $b$. Is it possible that after multiplying by $A$, the
   new vector happens to coincide with the second eigenvector? That is,
   $$
   A^{k}b=u_{2}%
   $$
   for some positive integer $k$. I assume the answer is no, but what exactly assures that this does not happen?

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5NmQ.png)